# How can I call a function assigned to a class's static array?

Tags: php, closures, static-variables

I am trying to add a function to a static variable in a class, and then call that function from elsewhere in my code.

This *works*:

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    static $myVar = [];
    static function set_myVar($function) {
        self::$myVar[] = $function;
    }
}

MyClass::set_myVar(function () { echo 'hello world!'; });
$t = MyClass::$myVar[0];
$t();

?>
```

However, this **does not**:

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    static $myVar = [];
    static function set_myVar($function) {
        self::$myVar[] = $function;
    }
}

MyClass::set_myVar(function () { echo 'hello world!'; });
MyClass::$myVar[0]();

?>
```

It results in the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: myVar in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\index.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\index.php on line 11

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP interpreter tries to evaluate `$myVar[0]()` before referencing the static array in your class.

You can test it if you place

```
$myVar = ["set_myVar"];
```

before your error and you get:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for MyClass::set_myVar()
```